# React-Redux - getting store from combined-reducers

Tags: redux, middleware

I've been writing some custom middleware. All I want to see is my store (as a chain of different state). Every reducer has its own state and combined it should give me my store.

```js
import {createStore, applyMiddleware, compose} from 'redux';
import rootReducer from '../reducers';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import {createLogger} from 'redux-logger';
import PouchDB from 'pouchdb';

const logger = createLogger({collapsed: true});

const customMiddleware = store => next => action => {
  console.log(store.getState());
  next(action);
}

export default function configureStore(initialState) {
    return createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(customMiddleware));
}
```

[This is what I get now:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6d0wf.png)

[This is what I expect to get:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L0i7R.png)

After adding isImmutable i tried this:

```js
const customMiddleware = store => next => action => {
  const state = store.getState();
  const storeTest = store.getState().toJS();
  console.log(storeTest);
  console.log(isImmutable(state) ? state.toJS() : state);
  next(action);
}
```

storeTest gives the wanted result, but the other log doesn't. 
[Any idea how to fix this?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UV9Ks.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your redux state is an [immutable](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/) `Map` rather than a plain object, so you'll need to convert it before logging it:

```
import { isImmutable } from 'immutable';

..

const customMiddleware = store => next => action => {
  const state = store.getState();
  console.log(isImmutable(state) ? state.toJS() : state);
  next(action);
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @Oblosys. I've still got one more question. I'll post it down below.

Comment: Maybe just create a new question for it? Comments are not really meant to ask questions in, and a fresh question will also attract other potential answerers.

Comment: Editing my questions seemed like a logical thing to do. Can still open a new question if u'd like.

Comment: Somehow `isImmutable` doesn't seem to test correctly. Hard to say what's going on exactly, as I don't know what the imports are and how the redux state is constructed. You could just test like this `typeof state.toJS === 'function' ? state.toJS() : state`.

Comment: Providing all my state is immutable, could it be an option to just not check if state (store.getState()) is immutable?

Comment: @Jorgi Sure, just be careful when using the middleware for other projects.

Comment: I'll keep in mind that when using immutable and combineReducers I should check if state is immutable! Thanks a lot.

Comment: @JorgiLeus You're welcome. If it answers your question sufficiently, you could choose to accept the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers (unless you're waiting for other, possibly better, answers)

Comment: I'm new to posting questions on here. Thank you for sharing so much valuable information. I've accepted your answer to be sufficient for my question.